# Get tweets using tokens

Tags: php

Is there any way to get tweet(twitter feeds) to our website. I have tokens(public and private key of twitter account) and i want do with tokens without using user name .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You have to use [Twitter REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api)